# Type error: unsupported operand type(s) for float and str while calculating Pearson coefficient

Tags: python, typeerror

My code is:

```
Data_clean=df.dropna()
print('association between.    ageuse and durationuse')    
print(scipy.stats.pearsonr(data_clean['S3D1Q2F'],data_clean['S3BD1Q2GR']))
```

S3D1Q2F and S3BD1Q2GR are the variable code names for age of usage and duration of use of a particular drug. Both the variables have numeric values.

And the error shown is Typeerror: unsupported operand type(s) :+ 'float' and 'str'

Please help me out in whatever way you can. Thank you.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Your current code fails in several respects.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [Pearson Correlation Coefficient](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html)

It accepts two numpy arrays whose data is either int or float.

So, data_clean['S3D1Q2F'] or data_clean['S3BD1Q2GR'] has data which is of type string.

So convert all the data inside the array using map()
and try calculating.

Comment: Can you please provide the syntax to convert the data inside the array using map() as you have suggested?

Comment: update the  example data of data_clean['S3D1Q2F'] and data_clean['S3BD1Q2GR']
in the question